# Error Undefined control sequence. \end{frame} in my beamer

Tags: beamer

I don't know what is wrong in code.

```
\begin{frame}{Introdução}
\justifying
O espalhamento elástico da luz é classificado em dois tipos, a depender do tamanho da partícula espalhadora:

\begin{itemize}
    \begin{block}
        \item espalhamento Mie: 
        \begin{itemize}
            \subitem dimensões das partículas espalhadoras são da mesma ordem ou maiores que o comprimento de onda da
            luz;
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}
        \item espalhamento Rayleigh:
        \begin{itemize}
            \subitem dimensões das partículas espalhadoras são muito menores que o comprimento de onda da luz;
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
    \end{itemize}

          \end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try replacing `\subitem` by `\item`. Also, all `\item` commands must be in a list environment (such as `itemize` or `enumerate`). Changing your code to `\begin{itemize} \item espalhamento Mie: \begin{itemize} \item dimensões ... \end{itemize} \end{itemize}`.

Answer (score 4):

thanks to @Eric Scöerg.

In the block environment, the heading of the argument block is mandatory(Forced).

% def in: **beamerbaselocalstructure.sty**

```
\newenvironment<>{block}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
```

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{}
text
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Your file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}% for \justifying

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Introdução}
\justifying
O espalhamento elástico da luz é classificado em dois tipos, a depender do tamanho da partícula espalhadora:

 \begin{block}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item espalhamento Mie: 
\begin{itemize}
\item dimensões das partículas espalhadoras são da mesma ordem ou maiores que o comprimento de onda da luz;
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{title}
\begin{itemize}
\item espalhamento Rayleigh:
\begin{itemize}
\item dimensões das partículas espalhadoras são muito menores que o comprimento de onda da luz;
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

See [LaTeX/List Structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures) And [Beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/).

Answer (score 2):

this is a working solution:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
The elastic scattering of light is classified into two types, depending on the size of the spreader particle:
    %\begin{block}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Mie scattering: 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item dimensions of the spreader particles are of the same order or greater than the wavelength of light
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    %\end{block}
    %\begin{block}
        \begin{itemize}
                \item Rayleigh scattering:
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item The size of the spreader particles is much smaller than the wavelength of light
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    %\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Please be sure to post a compilable (or at least an aspiring compilable) solution, e.g. a minimal example. In this case it is quiet obvious you are using the `\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}`. For less obvious problems, it can be frustrating to not know what packages are used. I've no clue why the `\begin{block} ... \end{block}` does not work though.