# Why not write a block title (forced argument), no error! But the output is not desirable

Tags: beamer, block

Why not write a block title (forced argument), no error! But the output is not desirable.

TexLive 2019

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{block}%{}
text 
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you put a **blank row** after the start of the block environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}%{}

text 
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Note that if the mandatory(Forced) argument is not written to the block environment it is error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}%{}
\begin{itemize}
\item text 
\end{itemize}    
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\end@
l.11 \end{frame}
```

Edit: Blank row after begin block, Not error!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}%{}

\begin{itemize}
\item text 
\end{itemize}    
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a bug?

Comment: No, not a bug. The argument is mandatory, so you _have_ to provide it. In the first case, the letter `t` is taken as the argument. I think you should use `\begin{block}{}` (with a blank argument) if you don't want to set a title.

Comment: So why not get it wrong! I was expecting an error.

Comment: TeX doesn't (usually) differentiate between `\begin{block}{t}ext` and `\begin{block}text`, so as far as it is concerned, you wanted a block titled `t` and the input is valid. With `\begin{block}%{} \begin{itemize}`, however, you get an error because it's the same as if you had written `\begin{block}{\begin}`, which is invalid because you didn't provide the argument to `\begin`.

Comment: Excuse me. Why not write a forced argument is not an error. if \begin{block}%{}

\begin{itemize} blank row not error!

Comment: True, the mandatory argument of the block environment must be written. But why in this case, Tex does not get the error

Comment: `\begin{block}%{}<newline>\begin{itemize}` (`<newline>` is an actual newline character) is the same as `\begin{block}\begin{itemize}` which as I already said is invalid. The `%{}` does nothing there: `\begin{block}%{}<newline>text` is the same as `\begin{block}text`, which is the same as `\begin{block}{t}ext`. `\begin{block}%{}<empty line>\begin{itemize}` is the same as `\begin{block}{\par}\begin{itemize}`, which seems to be valid. TeX Doesn't throw an error in the valid cases because, they are valid. If they make sense is a different problem. `\textcolor{red}text` works the same way...

Comment: it's true. Thanks.

Comment: I had answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514369/error-undefined-control-sequence-endframe-in-my-beamer/514391#514391) and this was a question for me